# Spreadsheet api hangs forever

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-sheets-api, google-cloud-platform

All of our server calls to get spreadsheet feeds hang forever. I can also duplicate from command line. What is going on?

curl https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1bGbeaSRQ-QYeKgPuXcv8vzvJqKO9r7Tq-nakeRs9JPQ/private/full?alt=json -H "Authorization: Bearer ""my-token"

Comment: Issue at Google likely https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3939